When opening an Edge window with Selenium, disable IE mode
'I want to open an Edge window in IE compatibility mode using Selenium.
When I open an Edge window without Selenium, the site automatically switches to IE mode upon access. However, when I open the window with Selenium, it does not switch to IE mode, and the existing browser settings are reset. Even if I change the IE mode to "compatible," the option to switch to IE mode remains grayed out and cannot be activated.
Is there any code to open an Edge window directly in IE mode using Selenium?'

If you want to start MS Edge in internet explorer mode. You'll need to use the internet explorer's webdriver and attach it to the edge browser's binary. This can be done as below:
Initialize the InternetExplorereOptions :
InternetExplorerOptions ieOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions();
ieOptions.attachToEdgeChrome(); // --> Required for IE Compatibility Mode
ieOptions.withEdgeExecutablePath("path to you ms edge installation"); // --> Required for IE Compatibility Mode
ieOptions.takeFullPageScreenshot();
ieOptions.destructivelyEnsureCleanSession();
ieOptions.enablePersistentHovering();
ieOptions.ignoreZoomSettings();
ieOptions.requireWindowFocus();
ieOptions.setCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings", true);

Initialize and start the Internet Explorer Driver Service :
InternetExplorereDriverSErvice ieDriverService = new InternetExplorerDriverService.Builder()
    .usingDriverExecutable(new File(System.getProperty("webdriver.ie.driver")))
    .usingAnyFreePort()
    .build();
ieDriverService.start();

Spawn the browser and execute your tests
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieOptions);
driver.get("https://www.google.com/");

You can also refer to the official documentation of MS Edge for running your tests in IE Compatibility mode: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/ie-mode
Note: Any limitations of running tests in IE will be applicable to these ms edge instances as well.
Reference: Python Selenium Edge Browser in Internet Explorer mode

So if you would like to have both Edge and IE mode window within the same driver instance, the answer is it is not possible.
Edge driver --> open any page in Edge mode forcibly.
IE driver --> open any page in IE mode forcibly.
The only way you can have Edge and IE mode window at the same time with Selenium is you should initiate 2 driver instances, 1 for Edge and 1 for IE mode. You can include them in 1 Selenium project.
For example in Python:
driver = webdriver.Edge()

# Open webpage in Edge mode
driver.get("https://bing.com")

ie_options = webdriver.IeOptions()
ie_options.attach_to_edge_chrome = True
ie_options.edge_executable_path = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft/Edge/Application/msedge.exe"
driver2 = webdriver.Ie(options=ie_options)

# Open webpage in IE mode
driver2.get("https://www.example.com")

